# Ignoring a nonexistent category

Tags: php, laravel

Attaching multiple categories to one article using:

```
public static function setCategory(Request $request) {
    
        $article = Article::where('id', $request->article_id)->first();

        $categories_ids = json_decode($request->categories_ids);

        $article->categories()->attach($categories_ids);
}
```

Suppose we enter the array [1, 2, 3, 4], and in it 4 is a nonexistent category. How can you make sure that all existing categories are added and 4 are simply ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in an elegant way, I'd do this:

```php
$article = Article::findOrFail($request->article_id);
$requestedCategoriesIds = json_decode($request->categories_ids);
$keyName = (new Category())->getKeyName();
$existingCategoriesIds = Category
    ::whereKey($requestedCategoriesIds)
    ->pluck($keyName);

$article->categories()->attach($existingCategoriesIds);
```

Comment: and if in a simple way, somehow through `Category::whereIn('id', $blog_categories_ids)`

Comment: check the list of all IDs and add the selected existing ones, I just don't understand a little how to implement it

Comment: That's exactly what `whereKey()` does. The benefit of using `whereKey()` over `whereIn('id' , ...)` is that you don't hardcode the name of the primary key column, so in theory you could rename it at some point. Key in this context just means the primary key. So `$keyName` will be `"id"`.